# Graph api returning empty results when @g is passed in the search string

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

I observed a weird issue, which could be a potential bug in graph api,

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@%22&$top=20
>   - works](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@%22&$top=20%20-%20works)
>
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@gr%22&$top=20
>   - Works](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@gr%22&$top=20%20%3E%20-%20Works)
>
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@g%22&$top=20
>   - Failure](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/?$search=%22name@g%22&$top=20%20%3E%20-%20Failure)

Did some one ever face this before? if yes, could you please share the fix, if found already.
thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Your second case has @gr and you mentioned it works?

Comment: yes, it works with @ and @gr but doesnt work with @g and it is strange.